# Compose draw autoresizable text that always inside defined rectangle using canvas

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

[image]

As defined in the image, xAxis's texts are going off from the blue rectangle below the xAxis.

Is it possible to make the text auto resizable to always fit inside the defined rectangle inrespect of defined textSize?

```
val xPoints: List<String> = listOf(
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
)

Canvas(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
    val rectWidth = (size.width - leftPadding - rightPadding) / xPoints.size
    
    //Draw x-Axis Text
    xPoints.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
        val offset = Offset(
            0f + leftPadding + (index * rectWidth) + (rectWidth / 2),
            graphHeight - (bottomPadding / 2)
        )
        val rect = Rect(offset, rectWidth / 2)
        drawRect(
            color = Color.Red,
            Offset(0f + leftPadding + (index * rectWidth), graphHeight - bottomPadding)
            , size = Size(rectWidth, bottomPadding)
        )
        rotate(degrees = -45f, rect.center) {
            drawIntoCanvas {
                it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
                    text,
                    rect.center.x,
                    rect.center.y,
                    xAxisTextPaint
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use `SubcomposeLayout` to first measure the composable in one slot, then calculate the desired scale factor and use it to wrap the composable in another composable with a scale modifier, and finally, layout the scaled composable in another layout slot.